# Object in R is integer but has length of 8364

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` from which I extracted a column called `Volume`. The code is as follows:

```
volume = aapl.us$Volume
```

In the console, I am told the following:

```
typeof(volume)
# "integer"

length(volume)
# 8364
```

How is this possible?

Comment: R doesn't really have scalar values. Things like integers are stored in vectors. Even if you have `x<-1` that `x` is just a vector of length one. The length tells you how many numbers are in the vector. Your `aapl.us` is likely a data.frame with 8364 rows so when you ask for the `Volume` column, you get all the values back at once.

Comment: But why isn't typeof(volume) not  equal to "vector"?

Comment: Because everything is a vector. The `typeof()` just returns the particular class type of that vector. There's no built-in command that would return "vector" as a class.

Comment: Some combination of these comments would make a fine answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case that you encounter is not strange behavior in R. It may sound unintuitive at first to users of other programming language where there is a distinction between a scalar (single number) and a vector (one-dimensional array).

---

R does not have "scalar" data. Simplest data structure in R is a vector, and it can be a numeric, character, factor, integer, logical, or complex-valued vector. A single number in R is a "vector of length one", and not a "scalar". A vector must contain data of the same type.

`typeof()` [returns the type of a variable](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/typeof) (see the link for further information). In your case, `Volume` is a vector that contains integers, and that vector has length 8364.